# Replacement function of html "mailto" in an email body

Tags: html, email, mailto

I'm trying to insert a link in an email, which an user can click on to open up a new email box with prefilled content and an empty recipient.

```
mailto: ?subject=Refer a friend&body=Hi dude try this thing out
```

Unfortunately most of my users' ESPs block this link due to the fact that the recipient is missing after `mailto:`. But I have to leave the recipient field blank because this is something the user will fill in.

Any advice on workarounds?

Comment: this is working fine for me    <a href="mailto:?subject=Refer a friend&body=Hi dude try this thing out">tell a friend</a>

Comment: This depends on the ESP. Most of my users use mail.qq.com, and that ESP is blocking the action. Thus the question for alternatives